# Akka round robin router doesn't respect number of instances

Tags: java-8, akka, actor

I have the following code:

```java
class ARouter {
    public static ActorRef getRouter(actorContext, param1, param2, routerName) {
        ActorRef router;

        try {
            RoundRobinPool roundRobinPool = new RoundRobinPool(1);
            Props props = Props.create(MyActor.class, param1, param2, param3);
            router = actorContext.actorOf(roundRobinPool.props(props), routerName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
            router = null;
        }

        return router;
    }
}
```

and somewhere in my code I do this

```java
ActorRef router = ARouter.getRouter(actorContext, param1, param2, routerName);
anObject.getAListOfItems().forEach(listItem -> router.tell(listItem, getSelf()));
```

I would expect to to see one thread because although I send the messages to the router to dispatch them to the actors, the router was created with only one routee (If I understand it correctly).

I tried with different number of instances but I always get 8 threads. The only think that worked (and of course "crashed") was setting `new RoundRobinPool(0)` which worked and the application protested that no actors were available.

No custom configuration file is used. Is there something in the logic of routers that I don't understand?

Comment: I am assuming that when you say you get 8 threads, you're logging something somewhere and see that different messaes are handled by different threads? If that's the case then, that is by design. Akka's actors run on a thread pool. Each messge processing can be run by an o fhe threads. This is by desing.

Comment: Yes exactly! What I see is although I have one actor, I see 8  messages being handled by that one actor at the same time. So I was expecting one actor to execute one message at a time.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you're asking (your code nowhere refers to threads), but in Akka, a dispatcher schedules an actor's message processing to run on a thread when that actor has a message to process.  The standard implementation leverages a thread pool (in 2.6, the default pool has a size equal to the number of cores (counting a hyperthread as a core), 2.5 by default uses a larger pool to guard against inadvertent blocking starving system components): an actor's message processing in that implementation can happen in any thread in the pool.

So if your actors are logging which thread they're running on, for instance, you may see that the actor is running on multiple threads.  This is generally desirable: the actor's one-message-at-a-time processing model still ensures safety, and not being pinned to a particular thread in turn means that with *n* threads in the pool, any combination of *n* actors can be processing at the same time.

There are alternative dispatcher implementations which will pin an actor to a thread: if actors A and B are both pinned to thread T, then B cannot process a message if A is processing a message.  In some scenarios, this reduces context-switch overhead and improves throughput at some cost to latency.

In general, an actor shouldn't care which particular thread it's running on.